# Unable to use a Custom UITableViewDataSource in Custom UITableView class

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to create a class that extends `UITableView` with it's own custom `DataSource`.

The class is called `SHCTableView`.

First I created a prototype class called `SHCTableViewDataSource.h` which extends `NSObject`.

Now I add the property to `SHCTableView.h`:

```
// the object that acts as the data source for this table
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SHCTableViewDataSource> dataSource;
```

I get the warning

> `Property type 'id<SHCTableViewDataSource>' is incompatible with type
>   'id<UITableViewDataSource>' inherited from 'UITableView'`

and in the `SHCTableView.m`

```
const float SHC_ROW_HEIGHT = 50.0f;

-(void)refreshView {
  // set the scrollview height
  _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.bounds.size.width, [_dataSource numberOfRows] * SHC_ROW_HEIGHT);

  // add the cells
  for (int row=0; row < [_dataSource numberOfRows]; row++) {

    // obtain a cell
    UIView* cell = [_dataSource cellForRow:row];

    // set its location
    float topEdgeForRow = row * SHC_ROW_HEIGHT;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, topEdgeForRow, _scrollView.frame.size.width, SHC_ROW_HEIGHT);
    cell.frame = frame;

    // add to the view
    [_scrollView addSubview:cell];

  }

}

#pragma mark - property setters
-(void)setDataSource:(id<SHCTableViewDataSource>)dataSource {

  _dataSource = dataSource;
  [self refreshView];

}
```

All instances of `_dataSource` give me an error:

> `Instance variable '_dataSource' is private`

and a bunch of other errors as well but they all seem to be caused due to the fact that `_dataSource` is private, which is probably related to the warning above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView already declared dataSource so it's not good idea to declare as same name.  Just declare

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SHCTableViewDataSource> customDataSource;
```

then

```
-(void)setDataSource:(id<SHCTableViewDataSource>)dataSource {
[super setDataSource:_dataSourceInterceptor]
  _customDataSource = dataSource;

 [self refreshView];

}
```

if you must do it then you can do it this way..

Create intermediate object as dataSourceInterceptor to set the original dataSource of the super class and implement dataSource functions. Don't set the self to dataSource it's not a good idea.

Comment: I tried doing this and I assigned the data to both the dataSource and customDataSource variables but the Table does not seem to be displaying the data values, If is switch the table back to UITable from my custom class it seems to work fine.